# Equation of first variation for a flow

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to derive the equation of first variation for a flow for a vector field.

Things I am told:  $\mathbf{F}$ is a vector field of class $C^1$ with a flow $\phi$ of class $C^2$.

From here I have to show
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}D_x\phi(\mathbf{x},t)=D\mathbf{F}(\phi(\mathbf{x},t))D_x\phi(\mathbf{x},t)$$

My intuition if to use the chain rule, since that's what the right hand side looks like, but how to get there is confusing.  I'm not quite sure of the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can you swap $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ and $D_x$ on the left hand side? Why?
2. By definition, what is $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(\mathbf{x},t)$?

Comment: Is it because the operators of differentiation are commutative?  And I'm thinking 2 is a vector field?

Comment: 1. What do you know about functions that are of class $C^2$? 2. What is the definition of flow?

Comment: Class two functions are at least differentiable twice and flow is a differentiable function that defines all the flow lines,

Comment: 1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives 2. $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(\mathbf{x},t) = \mathbf{F}(\phi(\mathbf{x},t))$.

Comment: Okay, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}D_x\phi=D_x\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\phi=\mathbf{F}\phi$?

Comment: It is equal to $D_x(F\circ\phi)$.

Comment: Which is where we invoke the chain rule?

Comment: You know how to do the question now.

Comment: So swapping the order of differentiation and then by definition of flow, finally using the chain rule we get our derivation?

Answer (score 0):

So after our discussion, i think this is how the direct proof goes;
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}D_x\phi(\mathbf{x},t)=D_x\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\phi(\mathbf{x},t)=D_x\mathbf{F}(\phi(\mathbf{x},t))$$
Here we can invoke the chain rule
$$D_x\mathbf{F}(\phi(\mathbf{x},t))=D\mathbf{F}(\phi(\mathbf{x},t))\cdot D_x\phi(\mathbf{x},t))$$